# Google Cloud(Stackdriver): MQL Date Time conversion from UTC to EST

Tags: datetime, google-cloud-stackdriver

Was hoping if anyone of anyone could assist - basically I am experiencing an issue where DateTime format in my Payload is UTC(Non human-readable format) "2022-03-02T20:48:29.847676541Z".
Now the intention is to convert this time format to regular "DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm:ss:ssss" format.

In Metric explorer, I tried using query

***metric.Timestamp is in UTC Format "2022-03-02T20:48:29.847676541Z"***

fetch cloud_function::logging.googleapis.com/user/metric_name | group_by[metric.IDmetric.Timestamp, string_to_timestamp("metric.Timestamp",'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S:%f')]

But I am getting an error "Expression for time series identifier column 'string_lit_string_to_timestamp' had type 'Date' which is not a valid time series identifier column type"

Was hoping to get some form of assistance, so I can convert UTC Date into a regular date time format.

Regards,